# How to compile using CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I download LibCurl from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html (zip type), after I extract, I notice there is Include and Lib folder that has source codes, so I copy those to CodeBlocks project and include it, however when I build it show error

```
fatal error: curl/curlbuild.h: No such file or directory
```

The file is inside Include folder and I have included in my project

[image: This is the project structure I create to compile LibCurl]

I am new in C++ and using CodeBlocks, I plan to compile the LibCurl library into static lib file and include in my project, how do I do it? Please help, since the LibCurl by default only come with dsw Microsoft Visual C++ project file and I need to compile it into CodeBlocks (GNU GCC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs/INSTALL file in CURL's source archive, you should build CURL from the command line. If you are using MinGW (bundled with CodeBlocks), you need to make sure the MinGW bin directory is in your PATH variable (`set PATH=<path_to_mingw>\bin;%PATH%`) and then run `mingw32-make mingw32` in CURL's root directory

Answer (score 0):

The **LibCurl** is other project?
Try put the Headers and the Includes of CURL in LearnCPP project.

Comment: Yes, because I want it to become a lib file and include in my project, how to achieve it? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to set the include dir to whatever directory has the `curl` folder.  Look for this in your compiler options - it should correspond to the `-I` option.  Note that if it includes a makefile, you should use that instead.  Enable it in the project settings.

Comment: hi max, what is makefile? Yes I think it include makefile since there is this file name, and how to use it?

Comment: @John A makefile is a special file formatted in a way that [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) can read.  It's a portable way to make sure your stuff can be compiled across a variety of platforms, assuming they have some form of `make` installed.  Normally, to invoke `make`, you would `cd` into the directory with the makefile and use `make TARGET`, where `TARGET` is the name of the thing you're trying to build.  I'm not sure how it works on Windows, as I've only used makefiles on Linux.  P.S. Code::Blocks provides facilities to import visual C++ files.